# mysql join translations table on locale or any other

Tags: mysql, join, locale

I am creating a website with products in different languages. I would like to get a list of products from my database with the name of the product. However, the name of the product is in the `translations` table and not every product has a translation for every language.

This is what the database looks like:

```
+-----------+       +---------------+       +-----------+
| Products  |       | Translations  |       | Languages |
+-----------+       +---------------+       +-----------+
| id        |       | product_id    |       | code      |
| ...       |       | language_code |       | ...       |
+-----------+       | value         |       +-----------+
                    +---------------+
```

What I would like to do is get all products with their name. The name should either be in the users locale, if this is not available it should be in English and if this is not available it should be in any locale that is available.

I am currently using this code, but if there is no name in the current locale it just returns `null`.

```
SELECT p.*, t.value 
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Translations t ON t.product_id = id
WHERE t.language_code = {{ locale }}
ORDER BY t.value
```

Is there a function in mysql that I can use to define this order of locales that should be searched for? The problem is that I only want one row per product in my resultset.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `LEFT JOIN`s, defaulting to English only when the first value is not available:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(t.value, teng.value) as value
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     Translations t
     ON t.product_id = p.id AND
        t.language_code = {{ locale }} LEFT JOIN
     Translations teng
     ON teng.product_id = p.id AND
        teng.language_code = 'EN'
ORDER BY value;
```

Note that the conditions on the language need to go in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I didn't know about the `COALESCE` function. :)